# how to pass arguments as a list in R function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have functions that has a lot of arguments. So I would like to create a list of arguments and pass them to the function.

As an example, take `?mean` function:

```r
mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...)
```

So lets say I want to calculate mean of `1:10`, assigned to variable `x`, but pass other arguments as a list:

```r
gm <- list (trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE)

mean(1:10, gm)
#R> Error in mean.default(1:10, gm) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

I tried to use `do.call` but do not work either.

```r
do.call(mean,list(1:10, gm))
#R> Error in mean.default(1:10, list(trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE)) : 
#R>   'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

Comment: To be complete, `do.call(mean,c(list(1:10), gm))`. note the difference in the shape (length) between the object returned with `list(1:10, gm)` and `c(list(1:10), gm)`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, your `gm` has the wrong shape for [`do.call`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/do.call), it interprets your option list as a `trim` argument.

To make the argument correct shape, use [`c`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/c):

```r
gm <- list(trim=0, na.rm=FALSE)
do.call(mean, c(list(1:10), gm))
[1] 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with `rlang::exec` and the unquote-splice operator, `!!!`.

```
rlang::exec(mean, 1:10, !!!gm)
#> [1] 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default arguments instead which may be convenient if you are doing this repeatedly as an alternative to using `do.call`. You can do this with `formals` as follows:

```r
f <- mean.default
formals(f)[match(names(formals(f)), names(gm))] <- gm

f(1:10)
#R> [1] 5.5
```

This has a few corner cases to watch out for. For one, I use `mean.default` and not `mean` as I otherwise have to place the argument from `gm` before the `...`.

Another alternative to `do.call` is to create a `call` and use `eval`:

```r
cl <- as.call(c(list(quote(mean), x = 1:10), gm))
cl
#R> mean(x = 1:10, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE)

eval(cl)
#R> [1] 5.5
```